# How to control which keyboard is displayed when a user touches a text field in iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am currently developing a web application to be run in iPad. How do I control which keyboard is displayed when a user touches a text field?

input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"

I have tried the above html codes which tested working in ITouch but in the Apple iPad SDK emulator, it imply brings up the normal keyboard.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: above codes refers to what exactly?

Comment: The iPad is still under NDA so no one who has access to the information can comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "numeric keyboard" in iPad. Look, the size of the iPad keyboard is 768x264, it is very awkward to put just 12 keys there.

This code gives the number/symbol plane which is the best you could do.